# Function to Multiply input and display

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have my form like this:

- `Product` dropdown
- `Quantity` text field
- `UnitPrice` display
- `TotalPrice` display

I have created a function to display the unitprice by querying the db when the dropdown is selected. Now i wanted to be able to display the TotalPrice when the quantity is typed in by multiplying the quantity and the UnitPrice. Understand that the below is the way to multiply but how do i apply it in my query. Included my code too.

```
<script>
function showUP(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getunitprice.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function multiply(Quantity)
{
var totalPrice= parseFloat(document.getElementById("UP"))*Quantity;
document.getElementById("TP").innerHTML= totalPrice;
}
</script>


    <table><tr>
    <th width-"18%>Quantity:</th>
    <td width="60%">
        <input type-"text" name="Quantity" value="" onkeyup= "multiply (this.value)" size="60" />
    </td>
    </tr></table>
<p></p><div id="UP"><b>UnitPrice: 0.00 </b></div><p>
<p></p><div id="TP"><b>TotalPrice: 0.00 </b></div><p>
```

getunitprice.php

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("db", $con);

 $sql="SELECT CostPrice FROM Product WHERE ProductCode = '".$q."'";

 $result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

 echo "<b>UnitPrice: ".$row2['CostPrice']."";


 }

    mysql_close($con);
       ?>
```

Comment: @MimiEAM editted my code according the Arun and i have posted it to my original question. The display changes but its showing NaN??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onBlur` instead of `onchange` event. You can also use `onkeyup` event on quantity textbox.

```
<script>
function multiply(qty)
{
    var totalPrice= parseFloat(document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML)*qty;
    document.getElementById("TP").innerHTML= totalPrice;
}
</script>

        <tr>
        <th width-"18%>Quantity:</th>
        <td width="60%">
        <input type-"text" name="Quantity" value="" onkeyup= "multiply (this.value)" size="60" />

        </td>
        </tr>

<p></p><div><b>UnitPrice: <span id="UP">0.00</span> </b></div><p>
<p></p><div id="TP"><b>TotalPrice: 0.00 </b></div><p>
```

Comment: it's displaying NaN when the quantity is changed

Comment: it's displaying NaN when the quantity is changed. im still wondering what is the code that is making it display like this

Comment: I have included my function for UnitPrice query too. if tht wld help. i believe i shldnt be using UP to multiply...

Comment: i change it to <p></p><div><b>UnitPrice: <span id="UP">0.00</span> </b></div><p>
<p></p><div><b>TotalPrice: <span id="TP">0.00</span> </b></div><p>  now it displays...UnitPrice: 4.50

TotalPrice: NaN

Comment: Great! Its showing now. i missed this .innerHTML. by the way for some cases it is displaying result as 0.9999999 can we limit the decimal point here to just 2 decimal point?

Comment: you have been a great help. I am a beginner. Now i'm in another dilemma. How do i get this UP and TP to be updated into DB :(??

Comment: @user1501784: Kindly delete the unhelpful comments from here. So that peers can prevent from any confusion. Thanks. :)